# Openssl 3.0 problem with existing BIO communication

Tags: c++11, openssl

BIO callback read and write methods SslBioWrite() and SslBioRead() are not getting called in openssl 3.0, while they were getting called in openssl 1.0.2 case due to which SSL_connect is failing.

Earlier below code was working in openssl 1.0.2 on Windows:-

```
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();

SSL_CTX *_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
const char *cphs = TLS1_TXT_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA":""SSL3_TXT_RSA_NULL_MD5; //many such ciphors
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(_ctx, cphs);
SSL_CTX_set_mode(_ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
SSL *new_ssl = SSL_new(_ctx);
SSL_set_verify(new_ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, SslVerifyCallback);

BIO_METHOD bio;    
memcpy(&bio, BIO_s_socket(), sizeof(BIO_METHOD));
bio.bwrite = SslBioWrite;
bio.bread = SslBioRead;
BIO *wbio = BIO_new(bio);
BIO_set_app_data(wbio, this);
BIO_set_fd(wbio, (int)_socket, BIO_NOCLOSE); //_socket is an already connected TCP socket
SSL_set_bio(_ssl, wbio, wbio); //_ssl is already setup ssl with ssl context
SSL_connect(_ssl); //==>> this works and gets connected
```

But in openssl 3.0, as BIO_METHOD structure has become opaque and BIO_s_socket() returns const BIO_METHOD pointer, above approach can't work. I tried below approach...

I tried below with openssl 3.0.8:-

```
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
OPENSSL_init_ssl(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_SSL_STRINGS | OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CRYPTO_STRINGS, nullptr);
OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CRYPTO_STRINGS, nullptr);
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL_CTX *_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
const char *cphs = TLS1_TXT_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA":"SSL3_TXT_RSA_NULL_MD5; //many such ciphors
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(_ctx, cphs);
SSL_CTX_set_mode(_ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

SSL *new_ssl = SSL_new(_ctx);
SSL_set_verify(new_ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, SslVerifyCallback);

const BIO_METHOD *bio = BIO_s_socket();
BIO_METHOD *tbio = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOCKET, "sslsocket");
assert(tbio);
assert(BIO_meth_set_write(tbio, SslBioWrite) == 1);
assert(BIO_meth_set_read(tbio, SslBioRead) == 1);
assert(BIO_meth_set_create(tbio, BIO_meth_get_create(biom)) == 1);
assert(BIO_meth_set_destroy(tbio, BIO_meth_get_destroy(biom)) == 1);
assert(BIO_meth_set_callback_ctrl(tbio, BIO_meth_get_callback_ctrl(biom)) == 1);
BIO *wbio = BIO_new(tbio);
BIO_set_app_data(wbio, this);
BIO_set_fd(wbio, (int)_socket, BIO_NOCLOSE); //_socket is an already connected TCP socket
SSL_set_bio(_ssl, wbio, wbio); //_ssl is already setup ssl with ssl context
SSL_connect(_ssl); ==>> this fails with error SSL_ERROR_SSL
```

Below errors I can see in the console (after using ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr)):-

D88E0000:error:10000079:BIO routines:BIO_ctrl:unsupported method:..\crypto\bio\bio_lib.c:570: D88E0000:error:10000079:BIO routines:bio_write_intern:unsupported method:..\crypto\bio\bio_lib.c:349:

BUT, I see, BIO_ctrl() or bio_write_intern() are not being used anywhere in the program explicitely.

Comment: Please show any errors you get after the failing `SSL_connect()` using `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Methods SslBioWrite() and SslBioRead() are not being called in new openssl 3.0 case, while they are getting called in openssl 1.0.2 case due to which SSL_connect is failing. Can someone guide why these callback methods for read and write are not being called in openssl 3.0?

Comment: @MattCaswell Below errors I can see in the console:- D88E0000:error:10000079:BIO routines:BIO_ctrl:unsupported method:..\crypto\bio\bio_lib.c:570:
D88E0000:error:10000079:BIO routines:bio_write_intern:unsupported method:..\crypto\bio\bio_lib.c:349:
BUT, I see, BIO_ctrl() or bio_write_intern() are not being used anywhere in the program explicitely.

Comment: BIO_ctrl is used in your app via `BIO_set_fd` which is just a macro around BIO_ctrl. Are you compiling your application in debug mode? If not all the code you put in the "assert" statements will be removed by the compiler and will not execute. This would explain the second failure since BIO_meth_set_write() would never be called. I suggest removing the asserts and have proper checks since those failures could occur in non-debug mode too.

Comment: Are you calling `BIO_METHOD *tbio = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOCKET, "sslsocket");` for *every* connection? [Per OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BIO_meth_new.html): "`BIO_meth_new()` creates a new `BIO_METHOD` structure. It should be given a unique integer `type` and a string that represents its name."  If you call it more than once, you're violating that constraint.  And `(int)_socket`?  What makes you sure a Windows `SOCKET` value can be crammed into an `int`?  `SOCKET` is a **pointer**:  `typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;`.  That does not fit into an `int` in Win64.

Comment: Thank you @MattCaswell and Andrew Henle, your feedbacks make sense. Will try these and post the results here.

Comment: @MattCaswell you were correct. I found there is a bug in openssl 3.0.* due to which BIO Method callbacks were not getting called. I upgraded to openssl 3.1.0 and now those callback functions have started getting called.